# class and defining __str__

Tags: python, string, class

This is the exercise:

Write the special method `__str__()` for `CarRecord`.

Sample output with input: `2009 'ABC321'`

`Year: 2009, VIN: ABC321`

The following code is what I have came up with, but I'm receiving an error:

`TYPEERROR: __str__ returned non-string`

I can't figure out where I went wrong.

```
class CarRecord:
    def __init__(self):
        self.year_made = 0
        self.car_vin = ''


    def __str__(self):
        return "Year:", (my_car.year_made), "VIN:", (my_car.car_vin)

   

my_car = CarRecord()
my_car.year_made = int(input())
my_car.car_vin = input()

print(my_car)
```

Comment: You are not returning a string from your `__str()__()` method.

Comment: return `"Year:" + my_car.year_made + "VIN:" + my_car.car_vin` or maybe use `fstring` for str formats

Comment: Use an f-string: `return f"Year: {self.year_made} VIN: {self.car_vin}"`

Comment: `return` is not like `print()`, separating the values with commas makes a tuple, it doesn't concatenate them into a string.

Comment: when you do `return "a", "b"` it's the same as `return ("a", "b")` i.e. you're returning a tuple (a tuple is very similar to a list) with 2 strings instead of one string. Change it to `return "Year: " + my_car.year_made + " VIN: " + my_car.car_vin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're returning a tuple using all those commas. You should also be using `self`, rather than `my_car`, while inside the class. Try like this:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Year: {self.year_made}, VIN: {self.car_vin}"
```

The `f` before the string tells Python to replace any code in braces inside the string with the result of that code.

Comment: that did it! thanks so much! i was missing the f and should have used {} instead of ().

Answer (score 0):

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model_year = 0
        self.purchase_price = 0
        self.current_value = 0
        def print_info():
            print('Car Info') # It specifies a print_info class method but doesnt actually need to print anything useful.

    def calc_current_value(self, current_year):
        depreciation_rate = 0.15
        car_age = current_year - self.model_year
        self.current_value = round(self.purchase_price * (1 - depreciation_rate) ** car_age)
    
    
    def print_info(self):
       print("Car's information:")
       print("   Model year:", self.model_year)
       print("   Purchase price:", self.purchase_price)
       print("   Current value:", self.current_value)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    year = int(input()) 
    price = int(input())
    current_year = int(input())
    
    my_car = Car()
    my_car.model_year = year
    my_car.purchase_price = price
    my_car.calc_current_value(current_year)
    my_car.print_info()
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```
def __str__(self):
       return "Year: {}, VIN: {}".format(self.year_made, self.car_vin)
```

The trick here is that you pull values from the top of the class as they are set later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This answer works for grading

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"Year: {}, VIN: {}".format(self.year_made, self.car_vin)`
```

This is easier to understand

```
def __str__(self):
    f"Year: {self.year_made}, VIN: {self.car_vin}")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).